# How to add an "active" class to dropdown based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current url is `http://localhost/app/home` and I have this navigation :

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-list"></i> 
    <span>Outlook</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="/home"><span>Sales</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Product</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Channel</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

What I expected:

```
<li class="dropdown active">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-list"></i> 
    <span>Outlook</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="/home"><span>Sales</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Product</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Channel</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I need to add an `active` class to the dropdown `li`, and `ul li` based on the current URL. Is there any simple solution with jQuery?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `select` tag? Surely that would be easier?

Comment: `document.querySelector('a[href="/home"]').parentNode.classList.add('active')`

Comment: @Lain : not tested yet, but i think its only add active class to one `li`... not with the `<li class="dropdown">`

Comment: @NoobnSad: That is indeed correct. I assumed the `querySelector()` was the part in question not the traversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers... this is my full code how to solve this

```
var url = window.location.href
var parts = url.split("/")
var route = parts[parts.length-1]

if(route){
  var link = $('a[href*="/'+route+'"]');
  link.closest('ul').closest('li').addClass('active');
  link.parent('li').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: the code is from @Raihan Kabir that i modified a little bit

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the href attribute is in the current URL with this function.

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").each(function() {
    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (window.location.href.indexOf(href)) {
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

> Please note that '/' will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a dynamic one. Right? Because routes are different. So to catch the route url we need to use dynamic value in this case `window.location.href`. This snippet will resolve the problem -

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href
    var parts = url.split("/")
    var route = parts[parts.length-1]

    console.log(route) 
    if(route){
      $('a[href*="/'+route+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.active { background: red !important } /* for example */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something below.

```js
var url = "http://localhost/app/home",
 parts = url.split("/"),
 last = parts[parts.length-1];
 
 if(last){
  $('a[href*="/'+last+'"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
 }
```

```css
.dropdown-menu .active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown active">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-list"></i> <span>Outlook</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
            <li class=""><a class="nav-link" href="/home"><span>Sales</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Product</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Channel</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```